# What is the purpose of the LowLag* advanced features in the MediaCapture class?

Tags: windows-runtime, media, video-capture, image-capture

I don't see a real difference between the LowLag* features (controlled by LowLagPhotoCapture, LowLagPhotoSequenceCapture and LowLagMediaRecording classes) and the more classic CapturePhoto* and StartRecord*/StopRecord* methods of the MediaCapture class.

What are their purpose ? What advantages have they over the classic methods ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They allow for lower latency to initiate the capture by arming the system through a `Prepare` call (or similar, where applicable) that allows for most of the initialization to be decoupled from the call to begin the capture.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In fact, I've just discovered that only LowLagPhotoSequence is optional and depends on the hardware. LowLagPhotoCapture and LowLagMediaRecord are always available.